# Java polynomial addition using linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, polynomial-math

I am trying to add two polynomials using linked lists, but my result always comes out as 0.0 and I'm not sure why. Any ideas where I went wrong or if I am even taking the right approach?

-poly is a pointer to the front of the linked list that stores the polynomial, initialized to null in a different section of the code

```
    public Polynomial add(Polynomial p) {
    Polynomial a = this; 
    Polynomial sum = new Polynomial();
    sum.poly = new Node (0,0,null);
    Node c = a.poly;
    Node d = p.poly; 

    while(c!=null || d!=null ){ //either list still has entries 
        if(c == null){
            sum.poly.term = d.term;
            d=d.next; 

        } else if(d == null){
            sum.poly.term = new Term(c.term.coeff, c.term.degree);
            c=c.next; 

        } else if(c.term.degree > d.term.degree){
            sum.poly.term = c.term;
            c=c.next; 

        } else if(d.term.degree > c.term.degree){
            sum.poly.term = d.term;
            d=d.next; 
        }
        else{ // degrees are the same so we add 

            float temp = d.term.coeff + c.term.coeff;
            c=c.next;
            d=d.next;
            if(temp ==0){ 
                continue; // do not store 
        }
            sum.poly.term = new Term (temp, c.term.degree);
        }

        sum.poly.next = new Node(0,0,null);
        sum.poly = sum.poly.next;  
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of this.poly before executing this function? Because if it is null like you said then you are setting the variable c and d to null which would cause your loop to not execute at all. Did you try debugging? It would be very useful to see what parts of the code the program gets to.

Comment: poly is the pointer to the front of the linked list, and it is initialized as null, but  this.poly should be a pointer to the front of the linked list storing the polynomial from the input, correct?

Comment: That sounds about right. c and d should become null only after you've called their .next a few times. Try checking how many times your while loop is executing by debugging or sticking a System.out.println("test") into it. Also you seem to be treating sum.poly.term differently in the first 2 if statements, perhaps it is a matter of the Term constructor being called.

Comment: I added test print lines and the code seems to work in the correct order, but I think that the problem is creating the new polynomial after every iteration of the while loop.